# Empty Functions - Placeholder?

Tags: delphi

so I was just looking through the Code of our inventory management system
and I saw some Snippet's of one of my Coworkers, all he does in some Functions is 
simply open them and insert a command in there for example

```
procedure TWerkStF.TBBtnStatiClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  inherited;
  //
end;
```

so i am wondering when you should do something like that and when is it usefull, are there some benefits?

Comment: Did you look up the documentation of the keyword `inherited` in Delphi? If so, what did it say?

Comment: Well, I am new to the Language but afaik it performs the code of the Component? But i can't imagine that this is usefull in any way... maybe i need to add, that there is nothing changed or overwritten in the component itself

Comment: "afaik it performs the code of the Component". No, that's not an accurate description of what `inherited` does. It's going to be difficult for you to make headway if you are reluctant to read the documentation and take on new learning.

Comment: To me, that looks like the original author forgot to implement the code for that function. The author probably wrote the new class, pressed Shift+Ctrl+C, which also added ìnherited;` if the function is an `override`, and added a comment (for a reason only known to him or her). Later on, it was never implemented nor removed. In other words, that looks like unfinished code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We use such functions/procedures most times to tell other Co-Workers where they should not change anything, the reason for that is because some events are just not fitting the needs of some Modules, therefore we "warn" each other with empty Functions.

Sounds wiered, i know.

Answer (score 3):

This is not useful, and has no benefits. Such a function can, and should, be removed.

The function in the question, by using `inherited`, simply searches in the super classes for a function of the same name, and if one is found calls it. If one is not found then no action is performed. As a rule, such a function, one that only calls `inherited`, does not modify the behaviour of the program. You can remove it without changing behaviour.

Comment: Thank you, sir! That was really helpful.

Comment: Although, in intermediate code, i.e. when I'm still writing a class, and press Shift+Ctrl+C, I get a lot of empty stubs. I then fill those with code, but of course I can't handle all at the same time. Then something like it can be found (`inherited;` generated by the IDE, comment added by me, usually telling what I want to do there). But not in finished code.When writing, I always insert comments starting with `//$$RV:` and always remove those ASAP by writing proper code.

Comment: As everyone has said it is useless code.  However, (while in the Delphi IDE editor) if you remove the single commented line in the method and then save the file, Delphi will remove the empty method for you.  The commented line prevents this behavior.   I find that when I'm working on GUI code, I tend to create events and then quickly add a comment line so that Delphi won't delete it before I've had a chance to fill-in some code (if I save it before adding that code, that is).  And, this (maybe bad) practice has led me have not a few artifacts exactly like this in some of my code.

Comment: One reason for dummy code or comments in such methods is to prevent the IDE from automatically cleaning up and removing the method.  If you insert an event handler using the forms designer but then fail to put any code into it the IDE will automatically remove the method and reference to it before compiling.  Putting something non-functional in there can be a useful way to keep the method there as a placeholder or reminder not to forget to fill it in... that said, leaving a relevant comment is probably the better option there, and definitely deleting the lot if it ends up not being needed.

Comment: @DaveOlson and J: yes, but only if they are generated event-handler stubs in a form unit. The IDE won't remove any other. And such generated event handlers are seldom (never?) virtual.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Agreed, `inherited` is completely silly to use to anchor a stub - a comment is the way to go if that's the intention.

Comment: @Rudy, Yes, I know - It will only automatically remove empty stubs that are `published`, thus the event handler stubs created for you are removed but it will also automatically remove any empty methods that you *manually* add to the published section.

Comment: @Rudy, I like your idea of adding something additional to the placeholder comment - I'm going to start doing that.

Comment: I just slap in a semi colon and trust myself to check difference properly when committing

Comment: I find it quite easy to look for all occurrences of $$RV. I do that in all my code, also comments for items that need consideration (e.g. optimization, or a better algorithm, or to check corner cases, etc.)

Comment: I also sometimes use it to put a debugger breakpoint in when I have lots of classes descended from the same ancestor but I am only interested in one. But I do try to remove them when I am done.

Comment: @DaveOlson: I don't think I ever made a method on a form `published`. Most of the time, any of my helper methods are private.

Comment: @Rudy  Me either; I just noticed long ago that was only empty published method that are auto-removed.

Comment: @J... Please note that `inherited` is not _completley silly_! If you use visual form inheritance, it will call the event handler of your base form if it is assigned.

Comment: @ventiseis If you remove the method entirely then it still gets called

Comment: @DavidHeffernan True. I didn't doubt that. But as I'm required to save forms often (the IDE keeps crashing), I often add an empty comment to my empty event handlers in unfinished forms. If I don't do that, the IDE deletes my event handler and I can't continue my work later. And of course, occasionally such empty event handlers make it into source control, perhaps looking silly for other devs.

Comment: @ventiseis This is only if you are overriding the corresponding event method in a descendent class (ie, in some `TMyButton` class, `protected procedure Click (Sender : TObject); override;` - it does absolutely nothing in a handler attached to an instance of a class (ie: `btn.OnClick := TBBtnStatiClick;`).

Comment: @J... [Hallvard writes](http://hallvards.blogspot.de/2006/04/published-methods_27.html): _you can use published methods to implement a very flexible, late-bound polymorphic dispatch mechanism_. So all `published` methods are `dynamic` and can be overriden without the override keyword. I don't find any official documentation about this, but it certainly works because I tried it yesterday with an simple example.

Comment: @ventiseis No, published methods are not `dynamic`, not `virtual`, unless they are declared to be so.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Then why is it working like this? Did you look at the blog post?

Comment: @ventiseis You're talking about something completely different.  A component event is implemented as a simple method pointer.  There is nothing to inherit.

Comment: @ventiseis What you are seeing is simply that the method with the same name hides the one from the parent class and is found by RTTI. Try calling the method on an object reference declared to be of the parent class. The dispatch is static.

Comment: You are right! I was mistaking it completely because I thought that `inherited` does some kind of dynamic dispatch. Took some time, but now I got it.

Comment: Inherited simply looks up the name in the parent class, excluding this class